# Convert to string without brackets

Tags: python-3.x, string

I'm writing a program in Python to provide the greatest difference between a list of floating point numbers and a target value.

The code I have written works, yet the output is not quite what I expected see below:

```
#Convert list of floating-point numbers representing foot length in inches to shoe size.

# Input: length, floating-point number
foot_length = [10.6, 11.0, 11.1, 10.3, 10.5, 10.8]

target = 10.7

difference = []

# Iterate over elements in list
for length in foot_length:
    if length == 0:
        difference.append(length)
        max_difference = max(difference)
    elif length < target:
        difference.append([round(target - length, 2)])
        max_difference = max(difference)

    else:
        difference.append([float(round(length - target, 2))])
        max_difference = max(difference)
        
print('The greatest difference is', str(max_difference))
```

What I expect the output to be: `The greatest difference is 0.4`.

I get: `The greatest difference is [0.4]`

I thought by casting as a `str` this would remove the square brackets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are appending elements in the form of list in your `difference` list. Thats why you are getting output as list. Remove square brackets while appending elements to `difference` list:

```
difference.append(round(target - length, 2))

difference.append(float(round(length - target, 2)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Converting to a string is a good idea, but you should change your print line to:

```
print('The greatest difference is', str(max_difference)[1:-1])
```

This slices from the from the second character to the second last character, thus removing the `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I think the error is due to round

```
foot_length = [10.6, 11.0, 11.1, 10.3, 10.5, 10.8]

target = 10.7

difference = []

# Iterate over elements in list
for length in foot_length:
    if length == 0:
        difference.append(length)
        max_difference = max(difference)
    elif length < target:
        difference.append(target - length)

    else:
        difference.append(length - target)

max_difference = max(difference)
print('The greatest difference is', max_difference)
```

i remove it and now it is working